# How to find two files content in different and uniq

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, cut

I need to get difference and uniq output with  two different file.

one.txt

```
The lightning and thunder
They go and come;
But the stars and the stillness
Are always at home.
```

two.txt

```
The lightning and thunder
They go and come;
Tyger! Tyger! burning bright
In the forests of the night,
What immortal hand or eye
But the stars and the stillness
Are always at home.
```

I want to get output in two different ways like this.

same.txt

```
The lightning and thunder
They go and come;
But the stars and the stillness
Are always at home.
```

diff.txt

```
Tyger! Tyger! burning bright
In the forests of the night,
What immortal hand or eye
But the stars and the stillness
```

Comment: Use `diff file file2`

Comment: The line "But the stars and the stillness" should not be in `diff.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your file `one.txt` contains `two.txt`, you can use `grep` together with `-f` for this. And then, `-v` to invert the output.

What matches:

```
grep -f f1 f2 > same.txt
```

See output:

```
$ cat same.txt
The lightning and thunder
They go and come;
But the stars and the stillness
Are always at home.
```

What differs:

```
grep -vf f1 f2 > diff.txt
```

See output:

```
$ cat diff.txt
Tyger! Tyger! burning bright
In the forests of the night,
What immortal hand or eye
```

From `man grep`:

> **-f** FILE, --file=FILE
>
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero
>   patterns, and  therefore  matches  nothing. (-f is specified by
>   POSIX.)
>
> **-v**, --invert-match
>
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is
>   specified by POSIX.)

Comment: True, @RaulAndres . As it is the case for the OP, I just updated indicating it.

Answer (score 0):

For the coincidences:

```
grep -f one.txt two.txt > same.txt
```

For the diffeerences:

```
cat one.txt two.txt| grep -f same.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of text doesn't matter. You could sort and do a comm .

Sort and store

```
 sort one.txt > one_sorted.txt
 sort two.txt > two_sorted.txt
```

After that do comm

```
 comm -3 one_sorted.txt two_sorted.txt > diff.txt 
 comm -12 one_sorted.txt two_sorted.txt > same.txt
```